# How can I programmatically log out of Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I followed [this guide](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/log-out-forge) from the Forge Community Blog.

The blog suggests loading an iFrame with the `src` attribute set to https://accounts.autodesk.com/Authentication/LogOut

```html
<iframe src="https://accounts.autodesk.com/Authentication/LogOut" />
```

Though the iFrame loads properly, the user does not get logged out of the Forge platform.

This method worked well until sometime this past week or so. Now, the user remains logged in.

However, manually opening a new window and navigating to the LogOut URL does log the user out.

This appears to be a new change but I cannot find any documentation for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I decided to open a temporary new window for the logout url. I'm not happy with the solution, but it functions.

```js
const newWindow = open('https://accounts.autodesk.com/Authentication/LogOut');
setTimeout(() => newWindow.close(), 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this in the past and so far I have not encountered any issue, basically goes to the Nodejs SDK to use the endpoint for sign out.

```
 // prepare sign out
  $('#signOut').click(function () {
    $('#hiddenFrame').on('load', function (event) {
      location.href = '/api/forge/oauth/signout';
    });
    $('#hiddenFrame').attr('src', 'https://accounts.autodesk.com/Authentication/LogOut');
    // learn more about this signout iframe at
    // https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/log-out-forge
  })
```

Comment: That's essentially the code I've used for the past few months. I've started having an issue with it in the last week or so.